# Moving the speedometer line along the semi-oval

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make the arrow move along the speedometer, depending on the value in js. The arrow does not move from the center, but near the speedometer, because the length of the arrow is less. I tried to calculate the arrow values from 0 to 50, and from 50 to 100, but at different values it can be seen that it is shifted incorrectly.

[speedometer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkL0O.png)
Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style> 
        .stack {
            position: absolute;
        }
        .indicator {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
        }
        
        .arrow {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 43%;
            transform-origin: -1px 35px;
            transform:rotate(0deg);
            z-index: 1;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="stack">
        <div class="arrow">
            <svg width="8" height="39" viewBox="0 0 8 39" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M7.02826 16.539L7.09717 38.5951C6.06756 38.5635 5.03438 38.5513 3.99852 38.5534C2.96266 38.5556 1.92805 38.5779 0.900383 38.6164L0.831473 16.5604L0.836825 16.5315L3.25073 9.76552C3.46954 9.14896 4.34122 9.14624 4.56592 9.76037L7.01828 16.5123L7.02826 16.539Z" fill="red"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="indicator">
            <svg width="129" height="53" viewBox="0 0 129 53" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M10.2682 27.7496C10.2682 27.7496 10.2633 27.7594 10.2584 27.7643C10.2584 27.7643 10.2535 27.7692 10.2535 27.7741C10.2388 27.7937 10.2193 27.8133 10.2046 27.8329C10.2046 27.8329 10.2046 27.8328 10.2046 27.8377C10.1899 27.8573 10.1703 27.8769 10.1507 27.8965C10.1409 27.9112 10.1263 27.9258 10.1165 27.9356C10.0969 27.9552 10.0822 27.9748 10.0626 27.9993C9.95004 28.1314 9.83746 28.2636 9.72488 28.3958C9.7053 28.4153 9.69062 28.4349 9.67593 28.4545C9.66614 28.4643 9.65636 28.479 9.64657 28.4888C9.64167 28.4936 9.63678 28.4985 9.63188 28.5083C9.63188 28.5083 9.63188 28.5132 9.62699 28.5181C9.6172 28.5279 9.6123 28.5377 9.60251 28.5475C9.60251 28.5475 9.59762 28.5524 9.59272 28.5573C9.59272 28.5622 9.58293 28.5671 9.57804 28.572C9.57804 28.572 9.57314 28.5818 9.56825 28.5818C9.55846 28.5915 9.55356 28.5964 9.54867 28.6062C9.54867 28.6062 9.53888 28.616 9.53888 28.6209C9.53888 28.6258 9.52909 28.6307 9.52909 28.6356C9.5242 28.6454 9.51441 28.6503 9.50951 28.6601C9.50951 28.665 9.49972 28.6699 9.49483 28.6748C9.49483 28.6748 9.48504 28.6845 9.48504 28.6894C9.48504 28.6943 9.47525 28.7041 9.47035 28.709C9.46546 28.7139 9.46056 28.7188 9.45567 28.7286C9.45567 28.7286 9.44588 28.7384 9.44588 28.7433C9.44098 28.7482 9.43609 28.7531 9.43119 28.7629C9.43119 28.7678 9.42141 28.7726 9.41651 28.7824C9.41651 28.7873 9.40672 28.7922 9.40183 28.802C9.40183 28.802 9.39693 28.8118 9.39204 28.8118C9.38714 28.8216 9.37735 28.8265 9.37246 28.8363C9.37246 28.8363 9.36756 28.8461 9.36267 28.8461C9.35777 28.851 9.35288 28.8608 9.34798 28.8656C9.34798 28.8656 9.34309 28.8705 9.33819 28.8754C9.3333 28.8852 9.32351 28.895 9.31862 28.8999C9.31862 28.8999 9.31372 28.9048 9.30882 28.9097C9.30393 28.9146 9.29903 28.9244 9.28924 28.9293C9.28924 28.9293 9.28435 28.9342 9.27946 28.9391C9.27456 28.9489 9.26477 28.9587 9.25988 28.9635C9.25988 28.9635 9.25988 28.9684 9.25009 28.9733C9.2403 28.9831 9.2354 28.9929 9.22561 29.0027C9.22561 29.0027 9.22561 29.0027 9.22072 29.0076C9.21582 29.0174 9.20603 29.0223 9.20114 29.0321C9.20114 29.0321 9.19625 29.037 9.19625 29.0419C9.18646 29.0517 9.18156 29.0614 9.17177 29.0712C9.17177 29.0712 9.17177 29.0712 9.16687 29.081C9.16198 29.0908 9.15219 29.0957 9.1473 29.1055C9.1473 29.1055 9.1473 29.1055 9.1424 29.1104C9.13261 29.1202 9.12772 29.13 9.11793 29.1398C9.11793 29.1398 9.11793 29.1447 9.11303 29.1495C9.10814 29.1593 9.09835 29.1642 9.09345 29.174C9.09345 29.174 9.09345 29.174 9.08856 29.1789C9.08367 29.1887 9.07388 29.1936 9.06898 29.2034C9.06898 29.2034 9.06408 29.2083 9.05919 29.2132C9.0494 29.223 9.04451 29.2328 9.03472 29.2425C9.03472 29.2425 9.03472 29.2426 9.02982 29.2523C9.02493 29.2572 9.02003 29.267 9.01024 29.2719C9.01024 29.2719 9.00535 29.2768 9.00045 29.2817C8.99556 29.2915 8.98577 29.3013 8.98087 29.3062C8.98087 29.3111 8.98087 29.3111 8.97108 29.316C8.96619 29.3209 8.96129 29.3258 8.9564 29.3356C8.9564 29.3404 8.94661 29.3453 8.94171 29.3502C8.93682 29.3551 8.93193 29.3649 8.92703 29.3698C8.92703 29.3698 8.91724 29.3796 8.91724 29.3845C8.91724 29.3845 8.90745 29.3943 8.90745 29.3992C8.90256 29.409 8.89277 29.4139 8.88787 29.4237C8.88787 29.4237 8.88298 29.4334 8.87808 29.4334C8.87808 29.4383 8.86829 29.4432 8.8634 29.4481C8.8634 29.4481 8.8634 29.453 8.8585 29.4579C8.84871 29.4677 8.83892 29.4775 8.83403 29.4922C8.83403 29.4922 8.83403 29.4922 8.82914 29.4971C8.72635 29.6243 8.61866 29.7516 8.51587 29.8838L9.95983 31.0536C10.5276 30.3537 11.115 29.6488 11.7073 28.9733L10.3074 27.7496H10.2682Z" fill="black"/>
                <path d="M6.76358 32.0864C6.76358 32.0864 6.75868 32.0913 6.75868 32.0962C6.75868 32.1011 6.74889 32.1109 6.744 32.1158C6.744 32.1158 6.7391 32.1256 6.73421 32.1305C6.72931 32.1403 6.72442 32.1451 6.71463 32.1549C6.71463 32.1549 6.70973 32.1647 6.70484 32.1696C6.69994 32.1745 6.69505 32.1843 6.69016 32.1892C6.69016 32.1892 6.68526 32.199 6.68037 32.199C6.67547 32.2088 6.66568 32.2186 6.66079 32.2235C6.66079 32.2235 6.65589 32.2284 6.651 32.2333C6.6461 32.2382 6.64121 32.2479 6.63631 32.2528C6.63631 32.2528 6.63631 32.2577 6.63142 32.2626C6.62652 32.2724 6.61673 32.2822 6.61184 32.292C6.61184 32.292 6.61184 32.2969 6.60694 32.3018C6.60205 32.3116 6.59226 32.3165 6.58736 32.3263C6.58736 32.3263 6.58736 32.3263 6.58736 32.3311C6.58247 32.3409 6.57268 32.3507 6.56779 32.3605C6.56779 32.3605 6.56778 32.3654 6.56289 32.3703C6.55799 32.3801 6.5482 32.3899 6.54331 32.3997C6.54331 32.3997 6.54331 32.3997 6.54331 32.4046C6.53841 32.4144 6.52862 32.4242 6.52373 32.4291C6.52373 32.4291 6.52373 32.4339 6.51884 32.4339C6.50905 32.4437 6.50415 32.4535 6.49436 32.4633C6.49436 32.4633 6.49436 32.4633 6.49436 32.4682C6.48947 32.478 6.47968 32.4878 6.47478 32.4976C6.47478 32.4976 6.47478 32.4976 6.47478 32.5025C6.46499 32.5123 6.4601 32.522 6.45031 32.5318C6.45031 32.5318 6.45031 32.5318 6.45031 32.5367C6.44052 32.5465 6.43563 32.5563 6.42584 32.5661C6.42584 32.5661 6.41115 32.5857 6.40136 32.6004C6.40136 32.6004 6.40136 32.6004 6.40136 32.6053C6.39157 32.6151 6.38668 32.6248 6.37689 32.6346C6.3671 32.6444 6.3622 32.6542 6.35241 32.664C6.34262 32.6738 6.33773 32.6836 6.32794 32.6983C6.31815 32.708 6.31326 32.7178 6.30347 32.7276C6.30347 32.7276 6.28878 32.7521 6.27899 32.7619C6.26431 32.7815 6.24962 32.806 6.23004 32.8255C6.22025 32.8353 6.21536 32.8451 6.20557 32.8598C6.19578 32.8696 6.19089 32.8794 6.1811 32.8892C6.1811 32.8892 6.1811 32.8892 6.1811 32.8941C6.17131 32.9038 6.16641 32.9136 6.15662 32.9283C6.14683 32.9381 6.14194 32.9479 6.13215 32.9577C6.13215 32.9577 6.11746 32.9822 6.10767 32.992C6.09299 33.0115 6.0783 33.036 6.05873 33.0556C6.05873 33.0556 6.05873 33.0556 6.05873 33.0605C6.04894 33.0703 6.04404 33.0801 6.03425 33.0898C6.02936 33.0996 6.01957 33.1094 6.01467 33.1192C6.01467 33.1192 6.01467 33.1192 6.01467 33.1241C6.00488 33.1339 5.99999 33.1437 5.9902 33.1535C5.9902 33.1535 5.9902 33.1584 5.9853 33.1584C5.98041 33.1682 5.97062 33.178 5.96572 33.1877C5.96572 33.1877 5.96572 33.1877 5.96572 33.1926C5.96083 33.2024 5.95104 33.2122 5.94615 33.222C5.94615 33.222 5.94615 33.2269 5.94125 33.2318C5.93636 33.2416 5.92657 33.2514 5.92167 33.2612C5.92167 33.2612 5.90699 33.2856 5.90209 33.2954C5.90209 33.2954 5.90209 33.3003 5.8972 33.3052C5.8923 33.315 5.88251 33.3248 5.87762 33.3346C5.87762 33.3346 5.87762 33.3346 5.87272 33.3444L5.85804 33.3689C5.85804 33.3689 5.85804 33.3737 5.85314 33.3786C5.84825 33.3884 5.83846 33.3982 5.83357 33.408C5.83357 33.408 5.82867 33.4178 5.82378 33.4178C5.81888 33.4227 5.81398 33.4325 5.80909 33.4374C5.80909 33.4374 5.80909 33.4423 5.7993 33.4472C5.79441 33.457 5.78462 33.4667 5.77972 33.4765C5.77972 33.4765 5.77483 33.4863 5.76993 33.4863C5.76504 33.4961 5.76014 33.501 5.75525 33.5108C5.75525 33.5108 5.74546 33.5206 5.74546 33.5255C5.74546 33.5304 5.73567 33.5402 5.73077 33.5451C5.73077 33.5451 5.72588 33.5549 5.72098 33.5597C5.71609 33.5646 5.71119 33.5744 5.7063 33.5842C5.7063 33.5891 5.69651 33.594 5.69162 33.6038C5.69162 33.6087 5.68672 33.6136 5.68183 33.6185C5.68183 33.6234 5.67693 33.6283 5.67204 33.6332C5.66714 33.643 5.66225 33.6479 5.65735 33.6576C5.65735 33.6625 5.64756 33.6674 5.64756 33.6723C5.64756 33.6723 5.64267 33.6821 5.63777 33.687C5.63288 33.6968 5.62309 33.7066 5.61819 33.7164C5.61819 33.7164 5.6133 33.7213 5.6084 33.7262C5.60351 33.736 5.59862 33.736 5.59372 33.7457C5.59372 33.7457 5.59372 33.7506 5.58883 33.7555C5.57904 33.7653 5.57414 33.7751 5.56435 33.7898C5.56435 33.7898 5.56435 33.7947 5.55946 33.7996C5.55456 33.8094 5.54966 33.8094 5.54477 33.8192C5.53498 33.829 5.52519 33.8485 5.5154 33.8583C5.5154 33.8583 5.5154 33.8583 5.5154 33.8632C5.50072 33.8877 5.48604 33.9073 5.47135 33.9269C5.38324 34.0541 5.29514 34.1765 5.20703 34.3038L6.73421 35.361C7.24816 34.617 7.7817 33.8779 8.32012 33.1535L6.8321 32.0424L6.76358 32.0864Z" fill="black"/>
                <path d="M3.5917 36.6729C3.09243 37.456 2.60784 38.249 2.13794 39.0517L3.74344 39.9915C4.19865 39.2133 4.67834 38.435 5.16293 37.6714L3.59659 36.6729H3.5917Z" fill="black"/>
                <path d="M127.665 41.0879C127.577 40.9215 127.484 40.7551 127.391 40.5887C127.317 40.4516 127.239 40.3097 127.161 40.1726C127.034 39.9474 126.906 39.7223 126.779 39.502C124.087 34.8324 120.91 30.4907 117.317 26.5504C117.033 26.2371 116.75 25.9287 116.456 25.6204C116.216 25.3609 115.971 25.1113 115.727 24.8568C115.545 24.6708 115.369 24.4848 115.183 24.3037C111.38 20.4661 107.166 17.0496 102.613 14.1469C101.747 13.5889 100.861 13.0505 99.9653 12.5317C95.2908 9.81994 90.2883 7.62218 85.046 6.02158C84.7963 5.94815 84.5516 5.87473 84.3069 5.80131C84.0817 5.73278 83.8516 5.66915 83.6265 5.60552C83.5971 5.59573 83.5726 5.58594 83.5384 5.58105C83.5188 5.57615 83.4992 5.56636 83.4796 5.56636C83.2594 5.50273 83.0342 5.44399 82.8139 5.38526C82.5643 5.31673 82.3147 5.2531 82.065 5.18457C76.8716 3.84339 71.4531 3.0798 65.8828 2.96232C65.6772 2.95743 65.4668 2.95254 65.2612 2.94764C64.9528 2.94764 64.6444 2.94275 64.3361 2.94275C64.0277 2.94275 63.7193 2.94275 63.4109 2.94764C63.2054 2.94764 62.9949 2.95254 62.7893 2.96232C57.219 3.0798 51.8005 3.84339 46.6071 5.18457C46.3575 5.2482 46.1029 5.31673 45.8582 5.38526C45.633 5.44399 45.4128 5.50273 45.1974 5.56636C45.1778 5.56636 45.1582 5.57615 45.1338 5.58105C45.1044 5.58594 45.075 5.59573 45.0456 5.60552C44.8205 5.66915 44.5904 5.73278 44.3653 5.80131C44.1156 5.87473 43.8709 5.94815 43.6262 6.02158C38.3789 7.62218 33.3862 9.81505 28.7068 12.5317C27.8111 13.0505 26.93 13.584 26.0587 14.1421C21.5066 17.0496 17.2872 20.4612 13.484 24.2988C13.4252 24.3624 13.3665 24.4211 13.3078 24.4799C13.0679 24.7197 12.833 24.9645 12.6029 25.2092C12.4952 25.3169 12.3973 25.4295 12.2896 25.5372L12.2799 25.5469C12.2799 25.5469 12.2407 25.5861 12.226 25.6057C11.9764 25.87 11.7218 26.1392 11.4771 26.4133C11.4428 26.4525 11.4135 26.4867 11.3792 26.521C11.3694 26.5308 11.3596 26.5357 11.3547 26.5455L12.6714 27.8622L16.8565 32.0472C17.5516 31.2836 18.2662 30.5347 18.9955 29.8005L14.8056 25.6106C18.5354 21.8416 22.6079 18.5425 26.9887 15.7378L29.9795 20.9165C30.8458 20.3585 31.7318 19.8249 32.6275 19.3061L29.6368 14.1274C31.9667 12.7813 34.375 11.5674 36.8566 10.4856C39.2355 9.45284 41.6536 8.55709 44.1107 7.80818L45.6673 13.6183C46.6511 13.3148 47.6448 13.0358 48.6531 12.7764L47.0966 6.96138C52.2067 5.64468 57.454 4.92514 62.7991 4.80767V10.8332C63.313 10.8185 63.8319 10.8136 64.3459 10.8136C64.8598 10.8136 65.3787 10.8185 65.8926 10.8332V4.80767C71.2377 4.92025 76.485 5.64468 81.5951 6.96138L80.0386 12.7764C81.042 13.0358 82.0357 13.3099 83.0244 13.6183L84.581 7.80818C87.0333 8.55709 89.4562 9.45284 91.8351 10.4856C94.3216 11.5625 96.725 12.7764 99.0549 14.1274L96.0642 19.3061C96.9599 19.8249 97.841 20.3585 98.7122 20.9165L101.703 15.7378C106.084 18.5425 110.156 21.8416 113.886 25.6106L109.696 29.8005C110.426 30.5298 111.135 31.2836 111.83 32.0472L116.015 27.8622C119.53 31.7242 122.594 35.919 125.188 40.4271L122.09 42.2137L120.093 43.364C120.612 44.2549 121.111 45.1604 121.586 46.0757L126.676 43.1389L128.282 42.2088C128.081 41.8319 127.885 41.455 127.68 41.083L127.665 41.0879Z" fill="black"/>
                <path d="M3.48414 40.4222L1.87864 39.4922C1.70733 39.8006 1.52622 40.104 1.3598 40.4173C1.29616 40.5299 1.23743 40.6425 1.1738 40.7502C1.11016 40.8627 1.05142 40.9753 0.992687 41.083C0.787106 41.455 0.586417 41.8319 0.390625 42.2088L2.00101 43.1388L7.09161 46.0757C7.5664 45.1604 8.06568 44.2548 8.58452 43.364L6.58744 42.2137L3.48903 40.4271L3.48414 40.4222Z" fill="black"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        value = 20
        transValue = (value - 100) / (0 - 100) * (-60 - 60) + 60;
        if (value <= 50) {
            leftValue = (value - 50) / (0 - 50) * (23 - 60.5) + 60.5;
            topValue = (value - 50) / (0 - 50) * (10 - -1) + -1;
            originValue = (value - 50) / (0 - 50) * (5 - -1) + -1;
        }
        else if (value > 50) {
            leftValue = (value - 100) / (50 - 100) * (60.5 - 90) + 90;
            topValue = ((value - 100) / (50 - 100) * (-1 - 23) + 23);
        }
        
        let arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');
        arrow.style.left = `${leftValue}px`;
        arrow.style.top = `${topValue}px`;
        arrow.style.transform = `rotate(${transValue}deg)`;
        arrow.style.transformOrigin = `${originValue}px 35px`;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried to implement this through other mathematical formulas, but I'm not good at it and I'm trying to find a more concise solution to the problem than I currently have

Comment: I'd consider doing it with vectors. (0) determine needle direction from value to display. Also compute intersection between gaugue elipse and an infinitely long needle (1) move in the opposite direction away from the ellipse (2) point calculated in #2 is position of needle-point (3) move needle_length * -1 * needle_direction units and there's the needle blunt end. This might help: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse-LineIntersection.html

Answer (score 2):

If you were to use css variables to aid in the positioning of and setting transform origin for the needle you can access and modify these easily with Javascript.

I set the transform origin for the needle/arrow at what would be the centre of the gauge ( or close to it ) based upon the initial value of 129px, round up for convenience to 130 ( see css vars )

To make the actual display of the arrow and gauge clearer the svg components were moved off-screen into symbols but then referenced using use elements (hint: you can have many svg elements contained like this for easy use! )

```js
const setstyle = (varname, value) =>
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(varname, value);

document.querySelector('input[type="range"]').addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  setstyle("--angle", `${e.target.value}deg`);
});
```

```css
:root {
  /* css variables which can be accessed and manipulated via Javascript */
  --gauge-width: 130px;
  --gauge-height: 55px;
  --arrow-width: 8px;
  --arrow-height: 40px;
  --angle: 0deg;
  --xoffset:5px;
  --ymult:1.35;
}

.stack {
  position: absolute;
}

.indicator {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}


/* 
      Use the css variables to determine size of SVG elements
      The transform-origin uses these also!
    */

.indicator svg {
  width: var(--gauge-width);
  height: var(--gauge-height);
}

.arrow svg {
  width: var(--arrow-width);
  height: var(--arrow-height);
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  /* 
      set position and origin properties using variables ~ 
      the 5px is required as an offset - not investigated why 
      */
  transform-origin: calc( 50% + 1px ) calc( var(--gauge-height) * var(--ymult) );
  transform: translate( calc( ( var( --gauge-width) / 2) - var(--xoffset)), calc( var(--gauge-height) * -1)) rotate( var(--angle));
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type='range' min='-60' max='60' step=1 value=0 />

    <div class="stack">
      <div class="arrow">
        <svg><use href="#arrow" /></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="indicator">
        <svg><use href="#gauge" /></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <svg id="icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" aria-hidden="true" style="position:absolute; width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; display:none">
        <symbol id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 8 39">
            <path d="M7.02826 16.539L7.09717 38.5951C6.06756 38.5635 5.03438 38.5513 3.99852 38.5534C2.96266 38.5556 1.92805 38.5779 0.900383 38.6164L0.831473 16.5604L0.836825 16.5315L3.25073 9.76552C3.46954 9.14896 4.34122 9.14624 4.56592 9.76037L7.01828 16.5123L7.02826 16.539Z" fill="red"/>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="gauge" viewBox="0 0 129 53">
            <path d="M10.2682 27.7496C10.2682 27.7496 10.2633 27.7594 10.2584 27.7643C10.2584 27.7643 10.2535 27.7692 10.2535 27.7741C10.2388 27.7937 10.2193 27.8133 10.2046 27.8329C10.2046 27.8329 10.2046 27.8328 10.2046 27.8377C10.1899 27.8573 10.1703 27.8769 10.1507 27.8965C10.1409 27.9112 10.1263 27.9258 10.1165 27.9356C10.0969 27.9552 10.0822 27.9748 10.0626 27.9993C9.95004 28.1314 9.83746 28.2636 9.72488 28.3958C9.7053 28.4153 9.69062 28.4349 9.67593 28.4545C9.66614 28.4643 9.65636 28.479 9.64657 28.4888C9.64167 28.4936 9.63678 28.4985 9.63188 28.5083C9.63188 28.5083 9.63188 28.5132 9.62699 28.5181C9.6172 28.5279 9.6123 28.5377 9.60251 28.5475C9.60251 28.5475 9.59762 28.5524 9.59272 28.5573C9.59272 28.5622 9.58293 28.5671 9.57804 28.572C9.57804 28.572 9.57314 28.5818 9.56825 28.5818C9.55846 28.5915 9.55356 28.5964 9.54867 28.6062C9.54867 28.6062 9.53888 28.616 9.53888 28.6209C9.53888 28.6258 9.52909 28.6307 9.52909 28.6356C9.5242 28.6454 9.51441 28.6503 9.50951 28.6601C9.50951 28.665 9.49972 28.6699 9.49483 28.6748C9.49483 28.6748 9.48504 28.6845 9.48504 28.6894C9.48504 28.6943 9.47525 28.7041 9.47035 28.709C9.46546 28.7139 9.46056 28.7188 9.45567 28.7286C9.45567 28.7286 9.44588 28.7384 9.44588 28.7433C9.44098 28.7482 9.43609 28.7531 9.43119 28.7629C9.43119 28.7678 9.42141 28.7726 9.41651 28.7824C9.41651 28.7873 9.40672 28.7922 9.40183 28.802C9.40183 28.802 9.39693 28.8118 9.39204 28.8118C9.38714 28.8216 9.37735 28.8265 9.37246 28.8363C9.37246 28.8363 9.36756 28.8461 9.36267 28.8461C9.35777 28.851 9.35288 28.8608 9.34798 28.8656C9.34798 28.8656 9.34309 28.8705 9.33819 28.8754C9.3333 28.8852 9.32351 28.895 9.31862 28.8999C9.31862 28.8999 9.31372 28.9048 9.30882 28.9097C9.30393 28.9146 9.29903 28.9244 9.28924 28.9293C9.28924 28.9293 9.28435 28.9342 9.27946 28.9391C9.27456 28.9489 9.26477 28.9587 9.25988 28.9635C9.25988 28.9635 9.25988 28.9684 9.25009 28.9733C9.2403 28.9831 9.2354 28.9929 9.22561 29.0027C9.22561 29.0027 9.22561 29.0027 9.22072 29.0076C9.21582 29.0174 9.20603 29.0223 9.20114 29.0321C9.20114 29.0321 9.19625 29.037 9.19625 29.0419C9.18646 29.0517 9.18156 29.0614 9.17177 29.0712C9.17177 29.0712 9.17177 29.0712 9.16687 29.081C9.16198 29.0908 9.15219 29.0957 9.1473 29.1055C9.1473 29.1055 9.1473 29.1055 9.1424 29.1104C9.13261 29.1202 9.12772 29.13 9.11793 29.1398C9.11793 29.1398 9.11793 29.1447 9.11303 29.1495C9.10814 29.1593 9.09835 29.1642 9.09345 29.174C9.09345 29.174 9.09345 29.174 9.08856 29.1789C9.08367 29.1887 9.07388 29.1936 9.06898 29.2034C9.06898 29.2034 9.06408 29.2083 9.05919 29.2132C9.0494 29.223 9.04451 29.2328 9.03472 29.2425C9.03472 29.2425 9.03472 29.2426 9.02982 29.2523C9.02493 29.2572 9.02003 29.267 9.01024 29.2719C9.01024 29.2719 9.00535 29.2768 9.00045 29.2817C8.99556 29.2915 8.98577 29.3013 8.98087 29.3062C8.98087 29.3111 8.98087 29.3111 8.97108 29.316C8.96619 29.3209 8.96129 29.3258 8.9564 29.3356C8.9564 29.3404 8.94661 29.3453 8.94171 29.3502C8.93682 29.3551 8.93193 29.3649 8.92703 29.3698C8.92703 29.3698 8.91724 29.3796 8.91724 29.3845C8.91724 29.3845 8.90745 29.3943 8.90745 29.3992C8.90256 29.409 8.89277 29.4139 8.88787 29.4237C8.88787 29.4237 8.88298 29.4334 8.87808 29.4334C8.87808 29.4383 8.86829 29.4432 8.8634 29.4481C8.8634 29.4481 8.8634 29.453 8.8585 29.4579C8.84871 29.4677 8.83892 29.4775 8.83403 29.4922C8.83403 29.4922 8.83403 29.4922 8.82914 29.4971C8.72635 29.6243 8.61866 29.7516 8.51587 29.8838L9.95983 31.0536C10.5276 30.3537 11.115 29.6488 11.7073 28.9733L10.3074 27.7496H10.2682Z" fill="black"/>
            <path d="M6.76358 32.0864C6.76358 32.0864 6.75868 32.0913 6.75868 32.0962C6.75868 32.1011 6.74889 32.1109 6.744 32.1158C6.744 32.1158 6.7391 32.1256 6.73421 32.1305C6.72931 32.1403 6.72442 32.1451 6.71463 32.1549C6.71463 32.1549 6.70973 32.1647 6.70484 32.1696C6.69994 32.1745 6.69505 32.1843 6.69016 32.1892C6.69016 32.1892 6.68526 32.199 6.68037 32.199C6.67547 32.2088 6.66568 32.2186 6.66079 32.2235C6.66079 32.2235 6.65589 32.2284 6.651 32.2333C6.6461 32.2382 6.64121 32.2479 6.63631 32.2528C6.63631 32.2528 6.63631 32.2577 6.63142 32.2626C6.62652 32.2724 6.61673 32.2822 6.61184 32.292C6.61184 32.292 6.61184 32.2969 6.60694 32.3018C6.60205 32.3116 6.59226 32.3165 6.58736 32.3263C6.58736 32.3263 6.58736 32.3263 6.58736 32.3311C6.58247 32.3409 6.57268 32.3507 6.56779 32.3605C6.56779 32.3605 6.56778 32.3654 6.56289 32.3703C6.55799 32.3801 6.5482 32.3899 6.54331 32.3997C6.54331 32.3997 6.54331 32.3997 6.54331 32.4046C6.53841 32.4144 6.52862 32.4242 6.52373 32.4291C6.52373 32.4291 6.52373 32.4339 6.51884 32.4339C6.50905 32.4437 6.50415 32.4535 6.49436 32.4633C6.49436 32.4633 6.49436 32.4633 6.49436 32.4682C6.48947 32.478 6.47968 32.4878 6.47478 32.4976C6.47478 32.4976 6.47478 32.4976 6.47478 32.5025C6.46499 32.5123 6.4601 32.522 6.45031 32.5318C6.45031 32.5318 6.45031 32.5318 6.45031 32.5367C6.44052 32.5465 6.43563 32.5563 6.42584 32.5661C6.42584 32.5661 6.41115 32.5857 6.40136 32.6004C6.40136 32.6004 6.40136 32.6004 6.40136 32.6053C6.39157 32.6151 6.38668 32.6248 6.37689 32.6346C6.3671 32.6444 6.3622 32.6542 6.35241 32.664C6.34262 32.6738 6.33773 32.6836 6.32794 32.6983C6.31815 32.708 6.31326 32.7178 6.30347 32.7276C6.30347 32.7276 6.28878 32.7521 6.27899 32.7619C6.26431 32.7815 6.24962 32.806 6.23004 32.8255C6.22025 32.8353 6.21536 32.8451 6.20557 32.8598C6.19578 32.8696 6.19089 32.8794 6.1811 32.8892C6.1811 32.8892 6.1811 32.8892 6.1811 32.8941C6.17131 32.9038 6.16641 32.9136 6.15662 32.9283C6.14683 32.9381 6.14194 32.9479 6.13215 32.9577C6.13215 32.9577 6.11746 32.9822 6.10767 32.992C6.09299 33.0115 6.0783 33.036 6.05873 33.0556C6.05873 33.0556 6.05873 33.0556 6.05873 33.0605C6.04894 33.0703 6.04404 33.0801 6.03425 33.0898C6.02936 33.0996 6.01957 33.1094 6.01467 33.1192C6.01467 33.1192 6.01467 33.1192 6.01467 33.1241C6.00488 33.1339 5.99999 33.1437 5.9902 33.1535C5.9902 33.1535 5.9902 33.1584 5.9853 33.1584C5.98041 33.1682 5.97062 33.178 5.96572 33.1877C5.96572 33.1877 5.96572 33.1877 5.96572 33.1926C5.96083 33.2024 5.95104 33.2122 5.94615 33.222C5.94615 33.222 5.94615 33.2269 5.94125 33.2318C5.93636 33.2416 5.92657 33.2514 5.92167 33.2612C5.92167 33.2612 5.90699 33.2856 5.90209 33.2954C5.90209 33.2954 5.90209 33.3003 5.8972 33.3052C5.8923 33.315 5.88251 33.3248 5.87762 33.3346C5.87762 33.3346 5.87762 33.3346 5.87272 33.3444L5.85804 33.3689C5.85804 33.3689 5.85804 33.3737 5.85314 33.3786C5.84825 33.3884 5.83846 33.3982 5.83357 33.408C5.83357 33.408 5.82867 33.4178 5.82378 33.4178C5.81888 33.4227 5.81398 33.4325 5.80909 33.4374C5.80909 33.4374 5.80909 33.4423 5.7993 33.4472C5.79441 33.457 5.78462 33.4667 5.77972 33.4765C5.77972 33.4765 5.77483 33.4863 5.76993 33.4863C5.76504 33.4961 5.76014 33.501 5.75525 33.5108C5.75525 33.5108 5.74546 33.5206 5.74546 33.5255C5.74546 33.5304 5.73567 33.5402 5.73077 33.5451C5.73077 33.5451 5.72588 33.5549 5.72098 33.5597C5.71609 33.5646 5.71119 33.5744 5.7063 33.5842C5.7063 33.5891 5.69651 33.594 5.69162 33.6038C5.69162 33.6087 5.68672 33.6136 5.68183 33.6185C5.68183 33.6234 5.67693 33.6283 5.67204 33.6332C5.66714 33.643 5.66225 33.6479 5.65735 33.6576C5.65735 33.6625 5.64756 33.6674 5.64756 33.6723C5.64756 33.6723 5.64267 33.6821 5.63777 33.687C5.63288 33.6968 5.62309 33.7066 5.61819 33.7164C5.61819 33.7164 5.6133 33.7213 5.6084 33.7262C5.60351 33.736 5.59862 33.736 5.59372 33.7457C5.59372 33.7457 5.59372 33.7506 5.58883 33.7555C5.57904 33.7653 5.57414 33.7751 5.56435 33.7898C5.56435 33.7898 5.56435 33.7947 5.55946 33.7996C5.55456 33.8094 5.54966 33.8094 5.54477 33.8192C5.53498 33.829 5.52519 33.8485 5.5154 33.8583C5.5154 33.8583 5.5154 33.8583 5.5154 33.8632C5.50072 33.8877 5.48604 33.9073 5.47135 33.9269C5.38324 34.0541 5.29514 34.1765 5.20703 34.3038L6.73421 35.361C7.24816 34.617 7.7817 33.8779 8.32012 33.1535L6.8321 32.0424L6.76358 32.0864Z" fill="black"/>
            <path d="M3.5917 36.6729C3.09243 37.456 2.60784 38.249 2.13794 39.0517L3.74344 39.9915C4.19865 39.2133 4.67834 38.435 5.16293 37.6714L3.59659 36.6729H3.5917Z" fill="black"/>
            <path d="M127.665 41.0879C127.577 40.9215 127.484 40.7551 127.391 40.5887C127.317 40.4516 127.239 40.3097 127.161 40.1726C127.034 39.9474 126.906 39.7223 126.779 39.502C124.087 34.8324 120.91 30.4907 117.317 26.5504C117.033 26.2371 116.75 25.9287 116.456 25.6204C116.216 25.3609 115.971 25.1113 115.727 24.8568C115.545 24.6708 115.369 24.4848 115.183 24.3037C111.38 20.4661 107.166 17.0496 102.613 14.1469C101.747 13.5889 100.861 13.0505 99.9653 12.5317C95.2908 9.81994 90.2883 7.62218 85.046 6.02158C84.7963 5.94815 84.5516 5.87473 84.3069 5.80131C84.0817 5.73278 83.8516 5.66915 83.6265 5.60552C83.5971 5.59573 83.5726 5.58594 83.5384 5.58105C83.5188 5.57615 83.4992 5.56636 83.4796 5.56636C83.2594 5.50273 83.0342 5.44399 82.8139 5.38526C82.5643 5.31673 82.3147 5.2531 82.065 5.18457C76.8716 3.84339 71.4531 3.0798 65.8828 2.96232C65.6772 2.95743 65.4668 2.95254 65.2612 2.94764C64.9528 2.94764 64.6444 2.94275 64.3361 2.94275C64.0277 2.94275 63.7193 2.94275 63.4109 2.94764C63.2054 2.94764 62.9949 2.95254 62.7893 2.96232C57.219 3.0798 51.8005 3.84339 46.6071 5.18457C46.3575 5.2482 46.1029 5.31673 45.8582 5.38526C45.633 5.44399 45.4128 5.50273 45.1974 5.56636C45.1778 5.56636 45.1582 5.57615 45.1338 5.58105C45.1044 5.58594 45.075 5.59573 45.0456 5.60552C44.8205 5.66915 44.5904 5.73278 44.3653 5.80131C44.1156 5.87473 43.8709 5.94815 43.6262 6.02158C38.3789 7.62218 33.3862 9.81505 28.7068 12.5317C27.8111 13.0505 26.93 13.584 26.0587 14.1421C21.5066 17.0496 17.2872 20.4612 13.484 24.2988C13.4252 24.3624 13.3665 24.4211 13.3078 24.4799C13.0679 24.7197 12.833 24.9645 12.6029 25.2092C12.4952 25.3169 12.3973 25.4295 12.2896 25.5372L12.2799 25.5469C12.2799 25.5469 12.2407 25.5861 12.226 25.6057C11.9764 25.87 11.7218 26.1392 11.4771 26.4133C11.4428 26.4525 11.4135 26.4867 11.3792 26.521C11.3694 26.5308 11.3596 26.5357 11.3547 26.5455L12.6714 27.8622L16.8565 32.0472C17.5516 31.2836 18.2662 30.5347 18.9955 29.8005L14.8056 25.6106C18.5354 21.8416 22.6079 18.5425 26.9887 15.7378L29.9795 20.9165C30.8458 20.3585 31.7318 19.8249 32.6275 19.3061L29.6368 14.1274C31.9667 12.7813 34.375 11.5674 36.8566 10.4856C39.2355 9.45284 41.6536 8.55709 44.1107 7.80818L45.6673 13.6183C46.6511 13.3148 47.6448 13.0358 48.6531 12.7764L47.0966 6.96138C52.2067 5.64468 57.454 4.92514 62.7991 4.80767V10.8332C63.313 10.8185 63.8319 10.8136 64.3459 10.8136C64.8598 10.8136 65.3787 10.8185 65.8926 10.8332V4.80767C71.2377 4.92025 76.485 5.64468 81.5951 6.96138L80.0386 12.7764C81.042 13.0358 82.0357 13.3099 83.0244 13.6183L84.581 7.80818C87.0333 8.55709 89.4562 9.45284 91.8351 10.4856C94.3216 11.5625 96.725 12.7764 99.0549 14.1274L96.0642 19.3061C96.9599 19.8249 97.841 20.3585 98.7122 20.9165L101.703 15.7378C106.084 18.5425 110.156 21.8416 113.886 25.6106L109.696 29.8005C110.426 30.5298 111.135 31.2836 111.83 32.0472L116.015 27.8622C119.53 31.7242 122.594 35.919 125.188 40.4271L122.09 42.2137L120.093 43.364C120.612 44.2549 121.111 45.1604 121.586 46.0757L126.676 43.1389L128.282 42.2088C128.081 41.8319 127.885 41.455 127.68 41.083L127.665 41.0879Z" fill="black"/>
            <path d="M3.48414 40.4222L1.87864 39.4922C1.70733 39.8006 1.52622 40.104 1.3598 40.4173C1.29616 40.5299 1.23743 40.6425 1.1738 40.7502C1.11016 40.8627 1.05142 40.9753 0.992687 41.083C0.787106 41.455 0.586417 41.8319 0.390625 42.2088L2.00101 43.1388L7.09161 46.0757C7.5664 45.1604 8.06568 44.2548 8.58452 43.364L6.58744 42.2137L3.48903 40.4271L3.48414 40.4222Z" fill="black"/>
        </symbol>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The arrow rotates around its axis. But I wanted to implement that the arrow was next to the speedometer. That is, when the distance from the speedometer and the arrow remained the same

Comment: If the gauge was semi-circular rather than elliptical it would be easier

Comment: Yes, that's why I came here for help

Comment: The nature of the problem was not particularly clear from the question itself. You might find that formulae for calculating points on an ellipse would be helpful?!

Comment: I agree with Professor Abronsius: currently it's  not clear  how the rendered result should look like (as  your example rather looks like a circle arc) . Ellipses are more tricky when it comes to get a point at a certain arc length. So you should at least know the initial/ideal rx/ry  radii values – recalculating these from your gauge path data (based on cubic beziers) is unnecessarily complicated. So please revise your description.